# pandas dataframe index: to_list() vs tolist()

Tags: python, pandas

I recently wrote a python script for someone, where I converted a pandas dataframe's index into a list using `to_list()`. However, this does not work for them, as they get: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_list'` with their python interpretter.

I did some searching and found that there is also `tolist()` that seems to do the same as `to_list()`: searching on [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) finds both, with word-for-word identical description.
On the other hand, the [documentation of Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html) mentions only `to_list()`.

So I wonder whether there is a difference between the two

- in functionality
- in popularity and/or "officiality"/endorsement
- in support in different version of pandas

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/base.py#L1183), you will see that right after `tolist()` code there is line `to_list = tolist`, so `to_list` is just alias for `tolist`

EDIT:  `to_list()` was [added in ver. 0.24.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html), see [issue#8826](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8826)

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on buran's answer (too much text to fit into a comment):
Using `git blame`on the pointed-out [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/base.py#L1183), one can see that `to_list()` was indeed added in December 2018 as an alias to `tolist()`. It was [commited](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/250dd5f7336196ac6e93744b671edddb449bd9cc) as an enhancement to resolve [issue 8826](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8826), i.e., to make it more inline with `to_period()` and `to_timestamp()`.

Moreover, changes and comments in `pandas/core/series.py` show that the original `tolist()` is "semi-deprecated":

```py
# tolist is not actually deprecated, just suppressed in the __dir__
_deprecations = generic.NDFrame._deprecations | frozenset(
    ['asobject', 'reshape', 'get_value', 'set_value',
     'from_csv', 'valid'])
     'from_csv', 'valid', 'tolist'])
```

Interesting to see how the system works...

Answer (score 4):

This question would need a pandas developer to be answered without doubts, but a reasonable guess would be that it serves as support for legacy versions.
As you can see from the source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/171c71611886aab8549a8620c5b0071a129ad685/pandas/core/base.py#L1183), the 'source' button for *to_list* forwards to the same source code of *tolist*, and the two functions are simply aliases.

Answer (score 1):

With all the above answers, only thing which we can get is that `to_list()` is just a alias of original `tolist()`.
I do noticed a difference though:
while converting a `pandas.DataFrame()` created with dict consisting `numpy.ndarray`, `to_list` throws an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_list'`, whereas `tolist` did the job.

```
dict = {'Name':['Martha', 'Tim', 'Rob', 'Georgia'],
        'Maths':[87, 91, 97, 95],
        'Science':[83, 99, 84, 76]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

output['OP.pool_results'] = df.values.to_list()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hshrima\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24028/1619690827.py", line 1, in <module>
    df.values[0].to_list()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_list'
```

But, if I use `tolist`, following is the result

```
df.values.tolist()
[['Martha', 87, 83], ['Tim', 91, 99], ['Rob', 97, 84], ['Georgia', 95, 76]]
```

Here, `tolist` refers to `ndarray.tolist`, whereas the above `to_list` refers to `IndexOpsMixin.tolist` from `pandas`

Comment: Note that the question was about __pandas__ `tolist` vs `to_list`. `pandas.DataFrame.values` returns a __numpy__ array and numpy indeed has only `tolist`. Indeed, if you read the discussion about the issue linked in the accepted answer, numpy's `tolink` is the reason why pandas used `tolink` and why they did not deprecate it after introducing `to_list`...

Answer (score 1):

In Python;
**tolist()** is a method of NumPy arrays that returns a list representation of the array.
**to_list()** is a method of Pandas dataframes that returns a list representation of the dataframe.

Although both methods return the same output, their differences lie in their origins and compatibility. `*to_list()*` is `Pandas-specific`.